# Cx_Freeze 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, cx-freeze

I am trying to compile a game I made for my friend. I cannot seem to get Cx_Freeze to work. I'm including tons of files, but I'm 99.9% sure I created the script correctly.

```
import cx_Freeze

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("game.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="Game",
    options={"build_exe": {"packages":["pygame"],
                           "include_files":["bup.wav","b1.png","b2.png","b3.png","b4.png","b5.png","b6.png","b7.png","b8.png","b9.png","b10.png","boss.png","enddead.png","endsuccess.png","eot.wav","flowerduet.wav","fromadam.mpg","fulllazer.png","hero.png","heroshot.png","hitbox.png","jan1.png","jan2.png","jan3.png","jan4.png","jan5.png","jan6.png","jan7.png","jan8.png","jan9.png","jan10.png","jan11.png","jan12.png","jan13.png","kys.ogg","lalegend.mp4","lazercharge.png","m1.png","m2.png","m3.png","m4.png","m5.png","m6.png","map.png","mharrived.png","midgame.ogg","obs.png","ps2p.ttf","s4h.wav","shoot.png","sos.mp4"]}},
    executables = executables

    )
```

Comment: Hard to tell without a traceback, but it looks like you need to provide a version number. cx_Freeze tries to split the version string on the period but it's not defined. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4828159/2202669).

Comment: This was the solution to my problem. I feel like an idiot for not figuring this out myself. Thanks very much!